# ng-click of anchor tag is not binding when adding rows dynamically in the datatable

Tags: angularjs

I am using the the bootstrap datatable with my angularjs application and in this am creating the link in a column dynamically by using the following code but i am unable to fire its ng-click function.If i return the simple html in the formatter fields its not firing and when i use $compile to return then it shows the object in that column.Its showing correctly in the datatable the problem is only its ng-click is not firing .How can i do it?

```
$scope.matterTableControl = {
options: {
queryParams: queryParams,
toolbar: "#get",
url: intakeAppFactory.getUserMatters(),
sidePagination: 'server',
showColumns: true,
clickToSelect: false,
maintainSelected: true,
columns: [
{
field: 'Name',
title: 'Matter',
align: 'center',
valign: 'bottom',
sortable: false,
formatter: matterNameFormatter
}]
}
};

function matterNameFormatter(value, row, index) {
return '<a href="javascript:void(0)"  ng-click="showValue(\'' + row.MatterId + '\')">' + value + '</a>');
}
```

Comment: Why the anchor tag is not properly closed? <a href="javascript:void(0)"  ng-click="showValue(\'' + row.MatterId + '\'

Comment: its properly closed its just typing mistake when i am posting it here.. its showing correctly in the datatable but its ng-click is not working  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) the html string and bind `$scope` to it.

```
function matterNameFormatter(value, row, index) {
    var newElement =  angular.element('<a href="javascript:void(0)"  ng-click="showValue(\'' + row.MatterId + '\')">' + value + '</a>'));
    $compile(newElement)($scope);
    return newElement;
}
```

You have to use `$compile` to compile the new element and bind the $scope to it.

P.S. I am assuming all of the code provided is inside the controller and both `$compile` and `$scope` will be accessible from `matterNameFormatter`

Comment: its returing [object][object]

Comment: @ManjitSingh what datatable plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using 
http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#integrate/angular

Documentation:
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

Comment: @ManjitSingh Can you make a js-fiddle?

Comment: i have never made this but i will try..... Please help if you found anything its urgent :(

Comment: I have created this please check it but its not showing output ..i think i am missing something    https://jsfiddle.net/manjitsingh/oub3bp0p/12/

Comment: Oh my god i found the answer here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255679/cell-button-in-datatables-using-angularjs
And thanks Minato for the help.